# Quickbook PHP API - get category list

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I need category list from Quickbooks Account.
So here I am using this query

> select * from Item where Type='Category'

But I get all the item list instead of the category list. What have I done wrong?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

> For Category, we have to change **minorVersion to 4**  in sdk.config
>   file of API.